# How to set Separate jaCoCo agent for projects in Tomcat

Tags: web-applications, tomcat7, code-coverage, jacoco

I have two projects in tomcat webapps, added jacocagent.jar to JAVA_OPTS. Is there a way to have seperate .exec reports for the two projects?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately AFAIK you must have two separates tomcats, each for webapp.